# Gitlab CI cache update

Tags: gradle, caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci

On GitlabCI I have caching setup and it is working properly:

```
  cache:
    key: gradle
    paths:
      - .gradle/caches
  before_script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
```

In order to speed up the process of uploading my cache (<20s); and take advantage of [this](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-runner/blob/337e5732877eff44ba1eb5b4270812eaf77f4fd9/commands/helpers/cache_archiver.go#L80-L85); I delete the "extra" files which have been updated during the build:

```
  after_script:
    - rm -rf .gradle/caches/$GRADLE_VERSION/
    - rm .gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin
    - find .gradle/caches/ -name "*.lock" -type f -delete
```

I expect CI to skip uploading the cache, since none of the files have been updated anymore. i.e.
Result of

```
    - find .gradle/caches/ -mmin -5 -exec ls -la {} +
```

is an empty list as well.

But that is not the case and my cache is uploaded on every job.

Am I missing something else? Has anyone else ran into this?